# Pip how to install from git with tag >= specific tag?

Tags: python, git, pip

I have a private packaged repo with tags.
I need to pin requirements in other package #2, and don't want to change them every time I change repo #1 (have new tag on every commit to master)
I need something like
`pip install -e git+ssh://git@github.com/***/repo1.git@1.0.*.0#egg=repo1` or
`pip install -e git+ssh://git@github.com/***/repo1.git@>1.0.5.0#egg=repo1`

How can I achieve it?

Comment: No way with tags. Use a branch that's always moved to the latest tag.